No module named 'utils.data_prep.features_eng
i am facing an error where the system is trying to import a class from a module it gives me an error:
No module named 'utils.data_prep.features_eng'

here is the module:
modules
this issue is in prep.py file.
any idea??
i have tried to rename the file but nothing happened

What import statement did you use?

Looking at your image, the utils folder seems to be under another directory (there's a vertical gray line besides it), if that's the issue, try adding the dir name to the front of utils:
import unknown_dir_name.utils.data_prep.features_eng

Other from that there's not much clue for me to repreduce the error and help you.
Maybe try edit the problem by giving minium amount of code that reproduce the same error.
